# Spring Boot Data / JPA - execute query with left join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to understand how to avoid many queries to fetch data from the relationship @OneToMany. From a performance point of view it would be by far faster left joining the two tables.

```
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}

@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee
{
    @Id    
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

Fetching data from Company entity will create

- 1 query to get data from COMPANY table
- many queries to fetch data for each employee from EMPLOYEE table

I read that:

- using Criteria API it is possible to force usage of JOIN
- using Hibernate annotation @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)

Is there any other way to do that keeping the Spring Data layer?

Comment: What is wrong with the solutions you have?

Comment: I don't want to execute many queries to fetch employees to populate the List<Employee>. I'm looking for a way where it can be fetched at once with Company joining Employee

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@NamedEntityGraph` and `@EntityGraph`annotations respectively on your entity class and repository to guide the JpaRepository queries strategy.